# How do I manually edit an Omeka theme

Tags: php, css, themes, content-management-system, omeka

I'm building a digital archive using Omeka Classic and I would like to place little flag icons that link to versions of my site in different languages in the header, so I’m trying to figure out how to tinker with the theme’s code (The theme is Minimalist). I don’t have a ton of programming experience, but I think I need to go to /themes/minimalist/common/header.php and add a php echo statement within the `<div class="site-title"></div>` tag to place my icons within the header section. And that’s as far as I can get on my own.

Questions:

Do I need to define my icons as a variable somewhere and then write an echo statement to the effect of: `<?php echo VARIABLE; ?>` Php at this level is above my head, but it looks like this is how content is being generated.

Could I add an echo statement in the location suggested above without using a variable or constant? Maybe something like this? `<?php echo <a class="lang" href="URL to Arabic language site"><img src="URL to flag image"/></a>; ?>` And then I could style the .lang class to push the flags to the bottom right corner of the site-title div.

Just wanted to ask before I start experimenting and break the site.